# How to disable lazy loading for complex type fields of generic type?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics, lazy-loading

I`m using EF to interact with my database.
I have implemented a generic repository:

```
public class GenericDbRepository<TEntity> 
        : IGenericRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
```

it has such method:

```
public virtual TEntity GetById(int id)
{
    using (MyDataContext context = new MyDataContext())
    {
       return context.Set<TEntity>().Find(id);
    }
}
```

Also there are two models:

```
public class Project
{
    public Project()
    {
        Tasks = new HashSet<Task>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public bool Enabled { get; set; }

    public State State { get; set; }

    public DateTime? ChangeDate { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Task> Tasks { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class Task
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int ProjectId { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int Interval { get; set; }

    public DateTime NextStart { get; set; }
}
```

In MyDataContext OnModelCreating method I`m linking models:

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<Project>()
            .HasMany(e => e.Tasks);
```

Everything works fine, when creating an instance of GenericDbRepository<Task> and execute GenericDbRepository(someId).

But if TEntity has complex type field (in my case it is ICollection<Task> Tasks), a have an exception "The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection".

I understand that MyDataContext was disposed after return value in GetById method and Tasks are not available after that.

I try to do this:

```
public MyDataContext()
    : base("name=MyDataContext") 
{
    this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
}
```

It helps a lot with described problem, but creates another one: Tasks not linking to Project and I`m always getting empty Tasks field. So, this not an option.

So, the question is how to get such complex type fields values before context dispose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason your navigation property is causing errors is because you're disposing the context, prior to the navigation property being loaded.

To avoid this kind of error you can eagerly load the `Tasks` for your `Project` using `Include` method in your generic repository,for example, you could do this:

```
 public virtual T FindElement(Func<T, bool> where, params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] navigationProperties)
 {
        T item = null;
        using (var context = new Entities())
        {
            IQueryable<T> dbQuery = context.Set<T>();

            //Apply eager loading
            foreach (Expression<Func<T, object>> navigationProperty in navigationProperties)
                dbQuery = dbQuery.Include<T, object>(navigationProperty);

            item = dbQuery
                  .FirstOrDefault(where); //Apply where clause
        }
        return item;
 }
```

Using this method you can find a element applying multiples includes, in your case, could be this way:

```
var repository=new GenericDbRepository<Project>();
var project=repository.FindElement(p=>p.Id==23, p=>p.Tasks, p=>p.State);
```

Comment: It's a workaround for my problem, but I see there some obstacles. It'll be okay if argument navigationProperties will be optional, but in this case it is required, otherwise I'll get an exception, so that is not very good.

Comment: I don't understand why you say this is not a good solution, This is the standard way to do several includes to a generic type. What are you trying to do when this exception is thrown?  Did you include all the navigation properties of your entity? I have updated my answer, check the end

Comment: I have to point to method some extra information, I would like to avoid doing that. Is there some another way to solve this?

Comment: I'm fraid this is the only viable solution when you have an escenario where your context is disposed.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [.Include](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738708(v=vs.110).aspx) method and include child properties you need before querying the parent entities.
[Here is a good article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx) about loading of related entities

Comment: Answers that only point to links outside StackOverflow are discouraged due to link rot.  Please post the relevant example into your answer directly.

Comment: This is good decision, in case when you know model type beforehand, unfortunately i have a generic type and don`t know what kind of type to expect. Is there any possibility to do that on model creating step?